# Difference between "lift" and "lift off" in Feynman Lectures

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Here's Figure 4.1:

[image: Figure 4.1]

And an excerpt from the [Feynman Lectures on Physics Chapter 4.2](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html):

> A very simple weight-lifting is shown in Fig. 4-1. This machine **lifts** three units "strong". We place three units on one balance  pan, and one unit on the other. However, in order to get it actually to work, we must **lift** a little weight **off** the left pan. On the other hand, we could **lift** a one-unit weight by lowering the three-unit weight, if we cheat a little by **lifting** a little weight **off** the other pan. Of course, we realize that with any actual lifting machine, we must add a little extra to get it to run.

It seems to me that Feynman is ascribing two different meanings to the verb "lift". One is getting the boxes in an upper position relative to the ground, and the other is removing weight from one of the pans of the machine (when "lift" is used in conjunction with "off").

Is my assessment correct?

Comment: Feynman's "we must lift a little weight" means "we must **remove** a little weight".

Comment: So the word "lift" is used to describe two different physical actions in this paragraph, no?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Feynman is trying to explain something in everyday language.

Comment: Thanks, Weather. Your comments make for a perfectly legitimate answer - I would award it as the solution if you posted it.

Comment: If you think that the writer uses the same word for "different physical actions", then you are missing that *lift off* is different from *lift*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, Feynman could have resolved this by using the word 'raise' instead of 'lift' when referring to the weight on the pan on the shorter arm of the balance.

Comment: @YosefBaskin that is correct, but to me (a non-native English speaker), the paragraph is nonetheless confusing. I had to re-read it many times to understand what it means.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - And of course if you were to lift the 3 blocks off the balance and allow the other side to reach equilibrium, and then suddenly drop the 3 back on, you might achieve lift off on the other side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lift) dictionary shows two meanings for

> **lift**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1** Raise to a higher position or level.
>
> **2** Pick up and move to a different position.

It is unfortunate that Feynman has created confusion in OP when trying to explain something in everyday language.

As [pointed out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552479/do-lift-and-lift-off-have-different-meanings-in-this-context/552480#comment1360377_552479) by @YosefBaskin, the author has used **lift off**, but it would have been clearer to say **remove**.

Comment: @YosefBaskin is correct, but Feynman's wording is still confusing. "lift" and "lift off" share a common denominator, that is, "lift".

Comment: Personally, I don't find this text confusing. Furthermore, during the 20 years I've been editing The Feynman Lectures on Physics, through which I've received thousands of reports of actual or purported errata, no one has ever complained to me that this text is confusing.

Comment: @MichaelA.Gottlieb not to you: but here the OP states he was confused.

Comment: @WeatherVane. Yes, the OP was confused, but I was responding to what *you* wrote, that "Feynman has created confusion," with which I disagree. I don't think the text is confusing, and as previously mentioned, no one has complained to me about it. I think the OP is confused for other reasons.

Comment: @MichaelA.Gottlieb this is splitting hairs, really, and is no reflection on your editing. If Feynman wrote (or spoke) those words, then they were his creation. Obviously he did not *intend* to cause confusion, but confusion there is, whether OP is the only confused person, or not. OP's [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552479/difference-between-lift-and-lift-off-in-feynman-lectures/552480?noredirect=1#comment1360412_552497) links to other sources of confusion.

Comment: @WeatherVane Feynman did not write those words, nor are those the exact words he spoke, but he read them and approved. There is no question of authorship: it is Feynman's text. But Feynman was not confused, nor is his text confusing. The confusion is in the OP's mind, not in Feynman's mind when he spoke (originally) nor in the edited text of his authorship. People can become confused for many reasons. The OP, for example, may not be a native speaker of English, in which case he may not have understood the text because of an imperfect comprehension of the English language.

Comment: @MichaelA.Gottlieb I have clarifed what I wrote in this answer, which did not even remotely suggest that Feynman was confused. I am confused though, since you say Feynman did not write those words, or speak them, yet it is Feynman's text. Good day to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116583/discussion-between-michael-a-gottlieb-and-weather-vane).

Comment: @WeatherVane - sorry to be confusing. The Feynman Lectures on Physics has three authors, Richard Feynman, Robert Leighton and Matthew Sands. Feynman gave the lectures, which were tape-recorded and photographed. From this material Leighton and Sands produced edited and illustrated text, which Feynman reviewed, then either approved or requested changes. Feynman did none of the writing himself (unless you include his lecture notes, which were recently published at feynmanlectures.caltech.edu).

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried to add to the above (but it was too late) that while the text of The Feynman Lectures on Physics closely follows what Feynman said in his lectures (excluding later editorial changes), it's not exactly the same: changes were made for readability.

Comment: @MichaelA.Gottlieb thank you, but the question isn't about Richard Feynman or the veracity of the transcribed lectures. OP just wanted to know the difference between the two uses of 'lift', and the confusion was in OP's mind, nowhere else.

Answer (score 3):

The verb "to lift" is combined with "off" to form a phrasal verb meaning "to get off the ground" when talking of rockets or aircraft. This is not the verb in question, of course, and the particle (adverb) is not separable; here the basic meaning of "to lift" (Raise to a higher position or level ([ref.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lift)) disappears because of the adverb "off" that has been added. (Remark: this is mentioned so as to provide an overview of how the particle "off" can be used with a verb or in connection with a verb.)

"Off", as an adverb, can be used with verbs to mean "so as to be removed or separated" ([Lexico, 2](https://www.lexico.com/definition/off)); the meaning of "lift" is the regular one but "off" adds a precision.  In this usage the particle is separable, or rather, so as not to use the vocabulary reserved for phrasal verbs, it doesn't have to be placed directly after the verb and pronouns  can be found there instead. This is still not the usage found in the paragraph.

> ‘If they must graze on the hillside, the reservoir must be **fenced off** to keep them at a safe distance.’
> ‘It matters not whether the brandy ignites, but the alcohol must be **boiled off**.’
> ‘The second-floor room was **sealed off** as officers carried out a detailed search.’

([ref. 1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xSo5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT234&dq=%22he+lifted+it+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwios7uhupbtAhVp6uAKHXI3DocQ6AEwBXoECGEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22he%20lifted%20it%20off%22&f=false)) He lifted it off and standing in a holder underneath were twelve wooden boxes.

([ref. 2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=a_BFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT89&dq=%22he+lifted+it+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwios7uhupbtAhVp6uAKHXI3DocQ6AEwBnoECGAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22he%20lifted%20it%20off%22&f=false))  When she sidestepped, it made it easier for him to undo the cinch on her saddle. He lifted it off with one hand ...
(same remark as precedingly)

In "*we must lift a little weight off the left pan*" and in "*by lifting a little weight off the other pan*", the word "off" is a **preposition** and has nothing to do with the verb or if it does it is a matter of purely semantic connection (You can lift a dish off a table but you can't think a dish off it); "off" is used to say that something has been removed or separated from something (in these instances, from the pan). ([Lexico, preposition 3](https://www.lexico.com/definition/off))

Answer (score 1):

If I lift Thing X off of Thing Y I *remove* it from Thing Y.

And, yes, "lift" has two meanings:  (1) to raise something higher, and (2) to apply an upward force on something, whether it moves or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that to lift is

transitive: I lift the weight - OED **1. a. To raise [something] into the air from the ground, or to a higher position; to elevate, heave, hoist**

intransitive: The weight lifts - OED  **3. intransitive for reflexive (also with up). (a) To rise. Said esp. of a vessel riding on the waves, occasionally of the waves themselves. Also in quasi-passive sense (e.g. of a window): To admit of being raised.**

Off is either an adverb ~ away or a preposition ~ from

The lectures are written verbatim with some, but not a lot, of correction. To those present, there would be no confusion, and I found none reading it.

I can see no need to change anything.

Comment: The lecture may not be logically flawed, but it can disorient some readers, especially non-native English speakers. The solution is simple: use an alternative wording for "lift off".

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Feynman's lectures were not intended as language learning exercises: they were addressed to some of the best young minds of the time, including non-native speakers, and were to teach them Physics. Your suggestion of rewriting them, is akin to suggesting all pre-20th century written works be translated into current English. The Master shows the way: the student makes the effort. :)

Comment: Feynman being a brilliant teacher does not rule out the possibility that this specific explanation has been poorly written. Please refer to [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190738/feynman-lectures-why-a-non-reversible-weight-lifting-machine-cannot-lift-higher), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191778/a-confusion-regarding-a-paragraph-in-the-feynman-lectures) and [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77703/how-to-understand-feynmans-reasoning-about-perpetual-motion?rq=1) for a preview of the many confusions caused by this chapter.

Comment: And the idea that my suggestion about this *specific* chapter is akin to re-writing *all* of the pre-20th century works is a non sequitur.

Answer (score -2):

lift - you just take something
lift off - you remove

Comment: "Lift off" is what comes after "... three, two, one".